# Laravel 8: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object al querer recuperar nombre de tabla externa

Tags: php, laravel, msql

tengo mi vista "show-client-wallet" donde muestro los creditos correspondientes a cada cliente,  llego al punto donde quiero mostrar el tipo de nota que tiene, si es Remisión o Ticket, Estos dos valores están en otra tabla llamada "types_paper" y al traerlos solo logro mostrar el ID y lo que busco es mostrar lo que hay en la columna "name" de la tabla "types_paper"

**vista show-client-wallet**

```
@foreach ($showcredit as $wallet)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="px-4 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-gray-900 geosanslgbold text-md">{{$wallet->id}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-4 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-gray-900 geosanslgbold text-md">{{$wallet->folio}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-4 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-gray-900 geosanslgbold text-md">${{$wallet->monto}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-4 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-gray-900 geosanslgbold text-md">{{$wallet->typepaper_id}}</div> <-----AQUI SOLO MUESTRO EL ID 

                            <div class="text-gray-900 geosanslgbold text-md">{{$wallet->types_paper->name}}</div> <-----SI LO UTILIZO ASI ME DA ERROR DEL TITULO
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-4 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                            <a href="" class="text-indigo-600 geosanslgbold py-2 px-3 rounded-md text-md border-2 border-indigo-600 hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600">Ver Abonos</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-4 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                            <a href="" class="text-indigo-600 geosanslgbold py-2 px-3 rounded-md text-md border-2 border-indigo-600 hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600">Reportar Pago</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

**ClientWalletController**

```
public function index($id)
{
    $clients = Client::Find($id);
    $showcredit = ClientWallet::where('client_id', $id)->get();
    return view('livewire.show-client-wallet', compact('clients', 'showcredit'));
}
```

**Tabla types_paper**

```
Schema::create('types_paper', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->string('name')->nullable()->default(null);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Tabla clients_wallets**

```
Schema::create('clients_wallets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->string('folio');
        $table->decimal('monto');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('client_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('typepaper_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->foreign('typepaper_id')->references('id')->on('types_paper')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Modelo TypePaper**

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table="types_paper";
protected $primaryKey="id";
protected $fillable =['name'];

public function clienttypes(){
    return $this->hasMany(ClientWallet::class);
}
```

**Modelo ClientWallet**

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table="clients_wallets";
protected $primaryKey="client_id";
protected $fillable = ['folio', 'monto', 'typepaper_id', 'client_id'];

public function paper(){
    return $this->belongsTo(TypePaper::class);
}
```

si alguien me podria ayudar, se los agradecería mucho

Comment: Buen día, puedes agregar la configuración de tus tablas y sus modelos?

Comment: listo añadí mas información

Comment: La relación se llama `paper`, pero estás poniendo `$wallet->types_paper->name ...`

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ   Me sigue dando el mismo resultado :(

Comment: Buen día, en el modelo ClientWallet intenta definir la relación de la siguiente forma `return $this->belongsTo(Model::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');`  Donde `foreign_key` es el nombre de la columna externa y `owner_key` la columna de `Model::class` que vas a relacionar Segun veo tus modelos y los nombres de las columnas quedaría así `return $this->belongsTo(TypePaper::class, 'typepaper_id', 'id');` Avisame si te funciona para poner la respuesta

Comment: Buen día, lo intentaré llegando a casa y aviso, gracias

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Listo, lo he probado y va de maravilla!! Muchas Gracias :D

Comment: @LuisMartínez, He escrito la respuesta para que la puedas aceptar y así ayudar a otros miembros que tengan el mismo problema. Al mismo tiempo ayudamos a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Como consejo adicional, te recomiendo buscar si alguien ha hecho la misma pregunta antes de crear una nueva. He dado la misma respuesta 4 veces en 2 días jajaja

Comment: @HeytalePazguato va que va, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el fin de resumir lo escrito en los comentarios y dar respuesta a la pregunta

Cuando usas relaciones belongsTo normalmente usamos un solo parámetro que es la clase con la que se va a relacionar el modelo.

```
$this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
```

Si no hay más parámetros, Laravel automáticamente busca relacionar la columna que se conforme con el nombre del modelo y concatena `_id` en tu caso sería `type_paper_id`

Hay ocaciones que queremos relacionar otra columna (O el nombre que le dimos a la columna no es igual al que laravel intenta utilizar) y entonces podemos utilizar el segundo parámetro de la relación para hacerlo, por ejemplo en tu caso sería

```
$this->belongsTo(TypePaper::class, 'typepaper_id');
```

Según la documentación de laravel 8 los parámetros que recibe belongsTo son de la siguiente forma:

```
return $this->belongsTo(Model::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');
```

Por lo tanto para que tu modelo funcione correctamente debes poner

```
return $this->belongsTo(TypePaper::class, 'typepaper_id', 'id');
```

Comment: muchas gracias :D lo había olvidado por completo